# What is the dimension of the space of all symmetric k-linear forms? What about the skew symmetric ones? What about the alternating ones?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the dimension of the space of all symmetric k-linear
forms? What about the skew symmetric ones? What about the alternating ones?

I am having a really hard time with this problem... Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the space of all symmetric $k$-linear forms on the $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

The dimension of the space of all skew-symmetric $k$-linear forms on the $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ if the characteristic of the field is 2 and $\binom{n}{k}$ if the characteristic of the field is greater than 2.

The dimension of the space of all alternating $k$-linear forms on the $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ is $\binom{n}{k}$.